# regex to add more criteria to check invalid phone numbers

Tags: regex, preg-match

Here is an expression that accepts indian phone numbers. What changes are required to put one more criteria to NOT accept following numbers without changing the functionality of existing expression
9999999999
8888888888
7777777777
9898989898
9797979797
8787878787
8989898989
7878787878
7979797979

Thanks

```
$input = trim($input); //get rid of spaces at either end
if (preg_match('/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?([789]\d{9})$/', $input, $m) == 1){
    return '+91'.$m[2];
```

Comment: I think it would be by far easier to simply go over the number and see how many different digits you have. If less than 2, then you reject the number.

Comment: It is really better to just add a second line of code, but you can try `^(?!(\d+)\1+$)(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?([789]\d{9})$`. This however, will add one more group and you will have to use `$m[3]`.

Comment: @npinti Thats a good logic. less than two or less than 1 if the same number is repeated 10x. My problem is syntax. How can I incorporate this in the existing working expression

Comment: @stribizhev will try this. will come back soon

Comment: @Sabha: Although a regex can work, splitting this in two steps would allow you to specify, for instance, a black list of numbers which you do not want to allow. This would make it easier to maintain the list of numbers you want to reject.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some negative lookahead in your regex to avoid matching repeated numbers:

```
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(?:\h*-\h*)?|0?)?(([789])(?!\2+$)(\d)(?!(?:\2\3)+$)\d{8})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR9jU8/1)

- `(?!\2+$)` will avoid the match if same digit is repeated till end.
- `(?!(?:\2\3)+$)` will fail the match when same 2 digit set is repeated till end.

Answer (score 0):

Put a negative lookahead before the last capture group to check if the two following digits are not repeated until the end:

```
$pattern = '~^(?>(?:\+|00?)?91(?:\s*-\s*)?|0)?(?!(.[789])\2+$)([789]\d{9})$~';

if (preg_match($pattern, $input, $m)) // testing if preg_match returns 1 is useless
    return '+91' . $m[2];
```

if you want to be less specific (with a second digit not in `[789]`) replace `(?!(.[789])\2+$)` with `(?!(..)\2+$)`.

Note: if you need to check other conditions, it can be useful to write your pattern in a more readable way like this:

```
$pattern = '~
# named groups definition
(?(DEFINE)  
    (?<repeated> (..) \g{-1}+ $ )
    (?<cond2> .* 666 )
    # etc.
    (?<badnum> \g<repeated> | \g<cond2> )
)
# main pattern
^
(?> (?:\+|00?)? 91 (?:\s*-\s*)? | 0 )? # optional prefix

(?! \g<badnum> ) (?<num> [789] \d{9} ) # last 10 numbers
$~x';

if (preg_match($pattern, $input, $m))
    return '+91' . $m['num'];
```

In this way, you don't need use multiple checks and your pattern stays easy to read and to maintain.